# Can't write to custom .plist

Tags: objective-c, plist

Please consider the following code:

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender{
        //create BFF with random id
        BFF * testBff = [[BFF alloc]init];
        testBff.relationType=@"BFF";
        testBff.id= [NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random() % 100)];
        testBff.handshake=[NSDate date];

        //Encode the object 
        //Since a .plist doesn't take custom objects, I convert my object into type NSData*

        NSData *encodedBFF = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:testBff];

        //Insert the data into the plist and save
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myBFFS.plist"];

        [data setObject: encodedBFF forKey:testBff.id];
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
  }
```

I would expect that every time I hit the button connected to this method, a new object would be added to `myBFFs.plist` residing in my documents folder.

-The Path seems to be fine

-The Variables Inspector indicates that the 'data' `NSDictionary`  contains a key with a value of type `NSMutableData`

Somehow, however, nothing is written to a file.

If I change

```
 [data setObject: encodedBFF forKey:testBff.id];
```

to

```
 [data setObject: @"foo" forKey:@"bar"];
```

a file IS written. So apparently, my encoding attempts failed?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: OK I've considered it.  What does this statement `if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])  { path = (same as previous value); }` achieve?

Comment: Oh, that is just some boilerplate code. See my updated question: writing to file works fine, but it seems that the structure of the file is not accepted. I will simplify my question to zoom in on the real problem.

Comment: What about getting some error information back?

Comment: is your class BFF implemented NSCoding ? take a look at the http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: Yes, it is. "encodedBFF" is populated, and of type "NSConcreteMutableData".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:
Apparently, the culprit was setting the key in this line:

> [data setObject: encodedBFF forKey:testBff.id];

which I changed to

> [myPlist setObject:encodedBFF forKey:[testBff.id stringValue]];